# Select locale translation info from non-default database

Tags: database

I setup 2 databases connections in settings.php, one is MySQL on which Drupal is installed and running, the other is Oracle from which sometimes reading some info non-relevant to Drupal as below:

```
db_set_active('OracleDB');
db_query('...');
db_set_active();
```

I forgot to catch exceptions for line 2. It works as designed. But some day, the Oracle server was down, and resulted a 500 error in Drupal, so I guess the line 3 had not been executed. Now, even the Oracle server is up, whenever the 3 lines are executed, it generates errors in Apache error_log as below:
[image]
We can see Drupal query locale translated strings(in fact and other things i.e. menu info, etc) against the Oracle database!
I've tried methods as below:

1. Set the oracle-query-codes module'weight to 999 or -999 in database
   and flush cache;
2. Diasble, uninstall and enable the
   oracle-query-codes module;
3. Find & replace the Oracle connection
   key(in settings.php) with 'default' or '' directly in Drupal MySQL
   database.

None worked.

Now, my website can run normally, except those pages need the execution of the 3 lines code of Oracle query.

So how to get it back in the track?